# How to jest mock code using in inside It block

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, ts-jest

I tried to jest mock at root level it's working fine. but jest mock used in inside It block is not working how to fix this issue.

**Model**

```
    email = (to: string, key: string) => {
        const emailParam = {
            from: 'yzx@gmail.com',
            to: to,
            subject: 'Hai',
            html: `<p>hello.</p>`
        };
        return Mailgun.sendEmail(emailParam);
    };
```

**Success Case**

```
                jest.mock('mailgun-js', () => {
                    const mockMailgun = {
                        messages: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
                        send: jest.fn(() => ({
                            id: '1',
                            message: 'Email send successfully.',
                        })),
                    };
                    return jest.fn(() => mockMailgun);
                });    

    describe('Email', () => {
        it('', async () => {
            const to = 'xyz@gmail.com'  
            const key = 1234
            // Executing
            const result = model.email(to, key);
            // Verifying
            expect(result.message).toBe('Email send successfully.');
            expect(mailgun.messages().send).toHaveBeenCalledWith(emailParams);
        });
    });
```

**Error Case**

```
    describe('Email', () => {
        it('', async () => {

          jest.mock('mailgun-js', () => {
               const mockMailgun = {
               messages: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
               send: jest.fn(() => ({
                        id: '1',
                        message: 'Email send successfully.',
               })),
             };
             return jest.fn(() => mockMailgun);
          }); 

            const to = 'xyz@gmail.com'  
            const key = 1234
            // Executing
            const result = model.email(to, key);
            // Verifying
            expect(result.message).toBe('Email send successfully.');
            expect(mailgun.messages().send).toHaveBeenCalledWith(emailParams);
        });
    });
```

I tried to jest mock inside the It block. It's not working throwing error. How to use jest mock function inside the It block.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to mock dependencies inside `it`. The usual way consists on providing mocks during the `beforeEach` method and eventually reset them using `afterEach`.

You can find additional information here: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2582